# How to match this strings with regular expressions?

Tags: python, regex

Im trying to match only the names with this input:

```
5 OK 377035 F 17949 , RICHARDS/PATRICIA MARIE A 15/01/19 2878-578482-3
6 OK 377599 F 13282 , ZARATE/NICOLAS A 38586778 15/01/19 2878-578486-0
7 OK 378583 F 23296 /*/*/*/, ASTAIRE/LUCY JANE A 17/01/19 3165-841179-4
```

This is the code so far:

```
import re, pyperclip, pprint

nombres = pyperclip.paste()

nombresReg = re.compile(r'\b\w+\b\s*/*,*\s*\b\w+\b\s?\b\w+\b')
mo = nombresReg.findall(nombres)
pprint.pprint(mo)
```

And this is the output im getting:

```
['5 OK 377035',
 'RICHARDS/PATRICIA MARIE',
 '01/19 2878',
 '3\r\n    6 OK',
 '377599 F 13282',
 'ZARATE/NICOLAS A',
 '01/19 2878',
 '0\r\n    7 OK',
 '378583 F 23296',
 'ASTAIRE/ LUCY JANE',
 '01/19 3165']
```

As you can see, it is matching the names, but its getting me a lot of crap with them... ive been trying for days now.

Any input would be appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you match an entire line and use a capturing group for the name? This avoids the possibility for multiple matches per line, some of them being junk.

Answer (score 1):

Group 1 from `,\s*(.*?)\s\w\s` will match everything after the only comma and a letter standing alone, e.g: *RICHARDS/PATRICIA MARIE*, *ZARATE/NICOLAS* and *ASTAIRE/LUCY JANE*.

Answer (score 0):

This pattern seems to be what you're looking for:

```
>>> pat = re.compile("[A-Z]+/([A-Z ]+ )+")
>>> s = '''5 OK 377035 F 17949 , RICHARDS/PATRICIA MARIE A 15/01/19 2878-578482-3
... 6 OK 377599 F 13282 , ZARATE/NICOLAS A 38586778 15/01/19 2878-578486-0
... 7 OK 378583 F 23296 /*/*/*/, ASTAIRE/LUCY JANE A 17/01/19 3165-841179-4
... '''
>>> pat.findall(s)
['PATRICIA MARIE A ', 'NICOLAS A ', 'LUCY JANE A ']
>>>
```

Explanation: "[A-Z]+/([A-Z ]+ )+" matches a sequence of one or more capital letters (`[A-Z]+`, followed by a literal slash(`/`), followed by one or more groups of capital letters which must be separated by a single space(`([A-Z ]+ )+`).